# How to use the parameters estimated by MCMC?

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, poisson-regression, jags

Considering this example, taken from the coursera course "Bayesian Statistics: Techniques and Models",

Dataset:

```
# This is the "badhealth" dataset from `library("COUNT")` in R

From German health survey data for the year 1998 only.

Format
A data frame with 1,127 observations on the following 3 variables.

numvisit
number of visits to doctor during 1998

badh
1=patient claims to be in bad health; 0=not in bad health

age
age of patient: 20-60
```

The model in jags:

```
model {
    for (i in 1:length(numvisit)) {
        numvisit[i] ~ dpois(lam[i])
        log(lam[i]) = int + b_badh*badh[i] + b_age*age[i] + b_intx*age[i]*badh[i]
    }
    
    int ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1e6)
    b_badh ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1e4)
    b_age ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1e4)
    b_intx ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1e4)
}
```

i.e. we are using the Poisson regression to model the `numvisit`.

After running `jags.model()` and `coda.samples()` using the data and the model, we got a list of parameter estimates:

```
           b_age   b_badh       b_intx       int
[1,] 0.007849244 1.488192 -0.009732432 0.3903787
[2,] 0.006821275 1.520971 -0.008907179 0.3839672
[3,] 0.006969045 1.496611 -0.009697216 0.4127674
[4,] 0.006941290 1.557291 -0.009249318 0.4048429
[5,] 0.007139250 1.536305 -0.011444426 0.4213547
...
total of N rows
```

Suppose that we want to answer the question:

> We have two people aged 35, one in good health and the other in poor health. What is the posterior probability that the individual with poor health will have more doctor visits?

This includes sampling `numvisit` using the estimated model parameters, there are few choices:

- using the mean or median of the MC samples of the parameters, i.e. `mean(b_age)`, `mean(b_badh)` as our estimates, calculate the corresponding lambda (poisson's paramter), and sample N (the row count of the parameters) numvisit using these estimates
- sample one numvisit from each row of the sampled model parameters

The author uses the later approach, justifying it with:

> Because we used our posterior samples for the model parameters in our simulation, this posterior predictive distribution on the number of visits for these two new individuals naturally takes into account our uncertainty in the model estimates. This is a more honest/realistic distribution than we would get if we had fixed the model parameters at their MLE or posterior means and simulated data for the new individuals.

The question:

I can see that there is certain logic to it, but I cannot get a better grasp of it, why it is "better" to sample once for different models, than sample many times from a single model? I can see that sample from different models gives you more variability (or does it? e.g. in the case of infinite of samples), but is there any rigorous theory says that, in this specific case, we want the variability introduced by sampling from different models? Or is this a experience/educated guess thing?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, using the first option (using posterior point estimates) would ignore uncertainty in the linear predictor, therefore ignoring uncertainty in lambda. The second option, which incorprates uncertainty in the linear predictor, would provide a full posterior distribution of lambda and therefore more appropriately capture uncertainty in numvisit in the posterior predictive distribution

Comment: @Lachlan - I don't think you misunderstood it; perhaps you should expand your comment to an answer!

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" addresses the question implicitly, focusing on the *predictive distribution*.

We have:
\begin{equation}
p(y_i|\lambda_i) = \textsf{Poisson}(y_i|\lambda_i) ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\lambda_i = e^{\beta\,x_i} .
\end{equation}
Let $D = (d_1, \ldots, d_n)$ where $d_i = (x_i,y_i)$.
The posterior distribution for $\beta$ can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
p(\beta|D) \propto p(\beta)\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i|\lambda_i) ,
\end{equation}
where $p(\beta)$ is the prior distribution.

Given the posterior distribution for $\beta$ and a specific value for the covariates $x_\star$, the *predictive distribution* for $y_\star$ is
\begin{equation}
p(y_\star|D,x_\star) = \int p(y_\star|\lambda_\star)\,p(\beta|D)\,d\beta ,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_\star = e^{\beta\,x_\star}$.
This distribution incorporates the uncertainty about the unknown parameter.
The mean of this distribution is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[y_\star|D,x_\star] 
&= \sum_{y_\star=0}^\infty y_\star\,p(y_\star|D,x_\star) \\
&= \int \left(\sum_{y_\star=0}^\infty y_\star\,p(y_\star|\lambda_\star)\right) p(\beta|D)\,d\beta = E[\lambda_\star|D] = E[e^{\beta\,x_\star}|D].
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The second equality reverses the order of summation and integration.
Note that $E[e^{\beta\,x_\star}|D] \ne e^{E[\beta|D]\,x_\star}$ owing to the nonlinearity of the exponential function.

Let $\{\beta^{(r)}\}_{r=1}^R$ denote the draws from the posterior distribution produced by the sampler.
We can make draws from the predictive distribution by drawing $y_\star^{(r)}$ from $p(y_\star|\lambda_\star^{(r)})$, where $\lambda_\star^{(r)} = e^{\beta^{(r)} x_\star}$.
If we are interesting in the mean of the predictive distribution, we can calculate the mean of the predictive distribution by taking the mean of the draws $\{y_\star^{(r)}\}$.

However, a more accurate (i.e., lower variance) way to compute the mean of the predictive distribution is to compute the mean of the draws $\{\lambda_\star^{(r)}\}$. (This is an example of what is known as *Rao-Blackwellization*.) Instead of making draws from the predictive distribution, we compute the density of that distribution and use that density of compute the mean.
We can approximate the predictive distribution using these draws:
\begin{equation}
p(y_\star|D,x_\star) \approx \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R p(y_\star|\lambda_\star^{(r)}) .
\end{equation}
This gives us the density for each value of $y_\star$.
We can approximate the mean of the predictive distribution:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[y_\star|D,x_\star] 
&\approx \sum_{y_\star=0}^\infty y_\star \left(\frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R p(y_\star|\lambda_\star^{(r)})\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R \sum_{y_\star=0}^\infty y_\star\,p(y_\star|\lambda_\star^{(r)}) 
= \frac{1}{R}\sum_{r=1}^R \lambda_\star^{(r)} .
%= \frac{1}{R}\sum_{r=1}^R e^{\beta^{(r)} x_\star}. 
\end{split}
\end{equation}